# save diferent outputs in array from select

Tags: postgresql

I have query with output where first 4 elements would be the same and the others different. I want to save these elements in array.
for example I have output:
[image]

where sid,name,time_from, time_to are the same values and id,type,count,from, to have different values.

I have query:

```
select asch.id as sid,
       asch.name, 
       asch.time_from,
       asch.time_to,
       array_agg(ad.id) as ad_id,
       array_agg(ad.type) as ad_type,
       array_agg(ad.count)as ad_count,
       array_agg(ad.from)as ad_from,array_agg(ad.to) as ad_to 
from ad ad
       join ad_ad_group aag on aag.ad_id=ad.id
       join ad_group ag on ag.id=aag.ad_group_id
       join ad_schedule asch on asch.ad_group_id=ag.id
       join ad_shedule_device asd on asd.ad_schedules_id=asch.id
       join device d on d.device_id=asd.devices_id
where d.device_id=4
group by asch.id
```

where depends on device_id Im selecting all ads on this device divide by ad shedule in which ad is located.
which output is:

[image]

but I want something like this:

[image]

Im really sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

```
select asch.id as sid,
    asch.name, 
    asch.time_from,
    asch.time_to,
    jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
        'ad_id'::text, ad.id,
        'ad_type'::text, ad.type,
        'ad_count'::text, ad.count, 
        'ad_from'::text, ad.from,
        'ad_to'::text,ad.to
    ))
from ad ad
    join ad_ad_group aag on aag.ad_id=ad.id
    join ad_group ag on ag.id=aag.ad_group_id
    join ad_schedule asch on asch.ad_group_id=ag.id
    join ad_shedule_device asd on asd.ad_schedules_id=asch.id
    join device d on d.device_id=asd.devices_id
where d.device_id=4
group by asch.id
```

Comment: It gave me error: 
ERROR:  function jsonb_build_object(unknown, integer, unknown, character varying, unknown, integer, unknown, date, unknown, date) does not exist
LINE 5:     jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
                      ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: function jsonb_build_object(unknown, integer, unknown, character varying, unknown, integer, unknown, date, unknown, date) does not exist
SQL state: 42883

Comment: @Hanka: Edited.

Comment: still ERROR:  function jsonb_build_object  does not exist. 
Problem is that I have postgreSQL version 9.3